# How to make inner UL list not inherit from outer UL List in CSS

Tags: css, list, inheritance

For the HTML List below, I need to add a background image only to the LI of the outer list.
(aka the one with class "menu-mlid-594 dhtml-menu expanded start-collapsed")

HTML codes are:

```
<li class="menu-mlid-594 dhtml-menu expanded start-collapsed ">
    About the Collection
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="leaf first dhtml-menu ">By Theme</li>
        <li class="leaf last dhtml-menu ">By Individual</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of hard to say what will work with so little contextual information, but in general you'll usually need to rely on cascading rules:

```
#outerULIdentifier li {
    background-image: url('someImage.jpg');
}
#outerULIdentifier li li {
    background-image: none;
}
```

I am assuming here that there is an ID or class on the outermost UL that you can reference.  Alternatively, you could do something like:

```
li.dhtml-menu {
    background-image: url('someImage.jpg');
}
li.dhtml-menu.leaf {
    background-image: none;
}
```

Although this latter version might have problems in IE 6 (which doesn't support multiple classes on a single element in a CSS selector very well).

Comment: I guess you meant _li.dhtml-menu .leaf_

Comment: Yeah, that would nicely work around the IE 6 issue. Dur, I so smart.

Comment: Duh, I missed some code quoted. Still I would prefer to override with a parent rule.

Answer (score 3):

```
li.menu-mlid-594 { your css rules here }
```

The above will only apply to li elements that have the class menu-mlid-594

Comment: Thanks. But I cannot do in this way because I have many such LI elements and they have different classes (menu-mlid-xxx). I have to work on other classes that are the same for all LI elements.

Comment: umm you can't add additional css rules?

Comment: Technically, I can. But I prefer not to do that. It is a menu tree generated by Drupal automatically. To add additional css rules or to change HTML codes, I have to write functions to overwrite default functions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul li {background:#F00;} /* First level */
ul li li {background:#FFF;} /* Second level */
```